# HTML :: Add links to input tags

Tags: javascript, html, input, toggle, href

I want to include a link to the `data-on` and `data-off` attributes so I can switch the website's idiom with a single click using a toggle. Have tried a script but no luck so far.

HTML:

```
<input id ="toggle" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="English" data-off="Spanish" type="checkbox">
```

JS:

```
function toggleEventInput() {
    $("#toggle").attr('data-on').html('<a href="/language/en"></a>');
    $("#toggle").attr('data-off').html('<a href="/language/es"></a>');
}
```

TIA

Comment: Are you attempting to put that link in the data-on/off attribute in place of English/Spanish?

Comment: English and Spanish are output as text on the toggle. I want those attributes (`data-on` and `data-off`) to have a `href` in order to switch from e.g. `http://en/contact` to `http://es/contact`

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to do this :

```js
function toggleEventInput() {
    $("#toggle").attr('data-on', '<a href="/language/en"></a>');
    $("#toggle").attr('data-off', '<a href="/language/es"></a>');
}

toggleEventInput();
```

```html
<input id="toggle" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="English" data-off="Spanish" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: Yeah, not really. That will replace 'English' and 'Spanish' by the `<a>` tag content. I want those attributes (`data-on` and `data-off`) to have a href in order to switch back and forth from e.g. `http://en/contact` to `http://es/contact`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Imagining that you are attempting to change the attribute value (data-on and data-off) you'll need to do the following:

```
$("#toggle").attr('data-on', '/language/en');
$("#toggle").attr('data-off', '/language/es');
```

This however isn't the result you want. The link will be in the data-on/off attribute, but just as data. Even if you add it with the `<a></a>` and someone clicked on it nothing would happen.

Add the link to the data like above and add a click event on the input (or something of the sort and do this):

```
$('#toggle').on('click', function(){
   location.href = $(this).attr('data-on');
});
```

But then again I'm supposing that this is what you wanted. GL.

Comment: Yeah, not really. English and Spanish are output as text on the toggle. I want those attributes (data-on and data-off) to have a href in order to switch back and forth from e.g.  `http://en/contact` to `http://es/contact`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this :

```
function toggleEventInput() {

  $("#toggle").attr('data-on' ,  '<a href="/language/en"></a>'); 
  $("#toggle").attr('data-off' , '<a href="/language/es"></a>');

}

toggleEventInput();
```

but i don't see the reason for this, this is an an attribute :)

Comment: Yeah, not really. That will replace 'English' and 'Spanish' by the `<a>` tag content. I want those attributes (`data-on` and `data-off`) to have a href in order to switch back and forth from e.g. `http://en/contact` to `http://es/contact`. Thank you!